# Jmeter 4.0: Not able to run maven test. Not picks .jmx tests

Tags: jmeter, pom.xml, jmeter-plugins

I have created maven project for jmeter4.0. 
My .jmx file is at /src/test/target location. 
When I runs 'mvn verify' command , it shows Build Success but in surefire-reports folder, there are no results/ Also there are no any logs showing test was run.
Can anyone please help me in sorting this. 
My pom.xml is as follows. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
  <version>jmeter</version>

  <name>jmeter</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [documentation](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin#reference-jmx-files-and-csv-data) the correct location of tests is `src/test/jmeter`

   > Once you have created your JMeter tests, you'll need to copy them to /src/test/jmeter. By default this plugin will pick up all the .jmx files in that directory, to specify which tests should be run please see the project documentation.
   >
   > You can also put data files in this folder and reference them in your plan.
2. The latest version of JMeter Maven Plugin is **2.7.0>**, it is compatible with [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) and you should be using the latest JMeter version as per [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Hi

I have set JMeter Maven Plugin to 2.7.0. I have created script using jmeter 4.0 version. But it didn't worked. 

Following are my system details. Can you please correct if I am missing anything. 

It would be great help.  

#mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre

Comment: Have you moved your .jmx file(s) to `src/test/jmeter` folder?

Comment: Yes. I have moved my .jmx file to src/test/jmeter folder. Also I have given 777 (read/write/execute) rights to all.  But still it's not pick ups the .jmx file.

Comment: Is there any option to send my scripts ?